# Symfony - Form redirect

Tags: symfony

I am building simple car renting app in Symfony for a programming class at my university.

On URL /search I show a form to user. Right now when the form is submitted user his /search again but different template is rendered

This is form code:

```
class SearchQueryType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('pickupCity', TextType::class)
            ->add('returnCity', TextType::class)
            ->add('pickupDateTime', DateTimeType::class, array(
                'years' => range(2016,2017),
                'error_bubbling' => true,
            ))
            ->add('returnDateTime', DateTimeType::class, array(
                'years' => range(2016,2017),
                'error_bubbling' => true,
            ))

            ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array(
                'label' => 'Find Car',
                'attr' => array(
                    'class' => 'btn-secondary btn-lg'
                )))
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\SearchQuery',
        ));
    }
}
```

And controller for this route:

```
class SearchController extends Controller
{
    public function searchAction(Request $request)
    {
        $query = new SearchQuery();

        $form = $this->createForm(SearchQueryType::class, $query);

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

            /* Some logic here */

            return $this->render('AppBundle:default:results.html.twig', array(
                'form' => $form->createView()
            ));
        }

        return $this->render('AppBundle:default:search.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView()
        ));
    }
}
```

However when the form is submitted I want to redirect to URL /results?SUBMITTED-PARMS-HERE, so user can send this link to someone and receive the same results. On /results again I wand to render form, this time filled with search params submitted and below render available car.

I don't know if its the best way to handle this problem, current solution works but link can't be send to someone else.

**EDIT:**

I change the code to fallowing:

```
 if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

            $data = $form->getData();
            $session = $this->get('session');

            $session->set('pickupCity', $data->getPickupCity());
            $session->set('returnCity', $data->getReturnCity());
            $session->set('pickupDateTime', $data->getPickupDateTime());
            $session->set('returnDateTime', $data->getReturnDateTime());

            return $this->redirectToRoute('results', array(
                'pickupCity' => $data->getPickupCity(),
                'returnCity' => $data->getReturnCity(),
                'pickupDate' => $data->getPickupDateTime()->format('d-m-Y-H-i'),
                'returnDate' => $data->getReturnDateTime()->format('d-m-Y-H-i'),
             ), 301);
        }
```

So as a result I receive URL ./results/Paris/Berlin/10-02-2016-10-00/17-02-2016-10-00

And in routing.yml:

```
results:
    path:     /results/{pickupCity}/{returnCity}/{pickupDate}/{returnDate}
    defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:Search:result}
    methods:  [POST]
```

Because I only want to receive POST request on this route and now when I submit form I get error page saying:

```
No route found for "GET /results/Paris/Berling/01-07-2016-00-00/01-11-2016-00-00": Method Not Allowed (Allow: POST)
```

Any idea how to fix it?

**EDIT 2:**

Never mind, my reasoning was bad.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but maybe using this example.

```
$this->redirect($this->generateUrl('default', array('pickupCity' => $pickupCity, 'returnCity' => $returnCity, 'pickupDateTime' => $pickupDateTimepickupDateTime)));
```

With your own parameter, which you can get where you put your comment

```
  /* Some logic here */
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getQueryString()` function.

Sample:

```
 if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
    return $this->redirect('results?'.$request->getQueryString());
 }
```